# Can't load dll when send application to another PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment, dll

I have the following solution:

```
MySolution
-Project: MyServer (WPF)
-Project: MyClient (WPF)
-Project: MyLibrary (Class library)
```

Inside `MyLibrary`, I reference an external DLL `System.Data.SQLite` for SQLite access. I set the dll to `Copy to local` so that when I build, it will copy the dll into the directory where the class library `MyLibrary` will be built into a dll.

In the other two projects (`MyClient` and `MyServer`) I reference the class library project so I can have access to my shared routines but also have access to the SQLite libraries. This works great on the dev machine, but when I copy the `Release` folder to another machine, the Client/server apps refuse to run throwing an error that it can't find the SQLite dll.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Regards

Comment: Does that `Release` folder contain your SQLite DLL? Could there be a 32-/64-bit issue here? (dev machine is 64-bit, target machine 32-bit or vice-versa)

Comment: compiling on 64bit machine but using settings "platform" set to "x86" on all projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you have a sqlite.dll in your release folder. You can install i using nuget with the Package Management Console command "Install-Package System.Data.Sqlite".

If you then get a "BadImageFormat" exception, make sure you are using the correct version of sqlite for your system. It comes in 32 and 64-bit flavors.